# Python 2 subprocess module vs Python 3 subprocess module differences

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess

I am trying to understand the differences between the Python subprocess module in both Python 2 and Python 3. I have a script that I need to make compatible with both Python 2 and Python 3. One of the changes I need to make is to the usage of the commands module, since this is deprecated in Python 3. The commands module has a function, getstatusoutput() - I have tested using the subprocess module in my Python 3 version, while keeping that function and it seems to work. However, if I was to use subprocess.getstatusoutput() in Python 2, I would get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getstatusoutput'
```

Has legacy support for that function, that was included in commands module, only been added to the subprocess module in the Python 3 version?

Comment: Making code that runs on multiple major Python versions is typically going to involve conditional imports, something like: `try:` / `from subprocess import getstatusoutput` / `except ImportError:` / `from commands import getstatusoutput`

Comment: Instead of using `getstatusoutput()`, just use something like `subprocess.check_output` which is available in both Python 2 and 3 with identical behavior.